# how to filter the product and optimize mongodb query?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

How to filter the product and optimize mongodb query,

We would like to get popular products base on some conditions i.e which products are orders, `view` and `likes`.

```
db.products.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "orders",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "product_id",
      "as": "orders"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "orderCount": {
        "$size": {
          "$cond": [
            {
              "$isArray": "$orders"
            },
            "$orders",
            []
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "likeCount": {
        "$size": {
          "$cond": [
            {
              "$isArray": "$likes"
            },
            "$likes",
            []
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "sumCount": {
        "$sum": [
          "$orderCount",
          "$likeCount",
          "$view"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "sumCount": -1
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/fIG3-yHGuV6

Have to use multiple `$addFields` what would be best option to achieve the products that have the most `orders`, `likes` and `views`. please guide

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest 2 corrections,

1. orders size does not need verification if it is an array or not condition because `$lookup` stage will always return in array
2. You can do both operations for `orderCount` and `likeCount` in a single `$addFields` stage

You final query would be,

```
db.products.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "orders",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "product_id",
      "as": "orders"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "orderCount": { "$size": "$orders" },
      "likeCount": {
        "$size": {
          "$cond": [{ "$isArray": "$likes" }, "$likes", []]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "sumCount": {
        "$sum": ["$orderCount", "$likeCount", "$view"]
      }
    }
  },
  { "$sort": { "sumCount": -1 } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Rc5g9c2V21v)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use projection to minimize the code

```
{
    "$project": {
      "likes": 1,
      "orderCount": {
        "$size": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              "$isArray": [
                "$orders"
              ]
            },
            "then": "$orders",
            "else": []
          }
        }
      },
      "likeCount": {
        "$size": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              "$isArray": [
                "$likes"
              ]
            },
            "then": "$likes",
            "else": []
          }
        }
      },
      "views": {
        "$ifNull": [
          "$view",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/qUNftLP_-PN

check the mongoplayground.